# Multiplication in homotopy groups and cobordism

Tags: differential-topology

Each homotopy class of a map of an n-sphere into the Thom space of the universal vector bundle determines a cobordism class of embedded smooth manifolds in Euclidean space.

How do the cobordism classes change when two elements of the homotopy group are multiplied?